# Jquery, Set an option from dropdown list by a textbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server-2008-r2

```
// JQuery script
<script>
$(function(){
$('.select-change').click(function(){

????
```

//what would come here to put textbox's text of con_name_class inside dropdown1 dropdownlist!!

```
});
});
</script>
```

Now the PHP and HTML code

```
<?PHP

connection...blah blah

while($record=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$recordx = $record['x'];
$recordy = $record['y'];
$recordz = $record['z'];
}
?>


<input type="text" class="con_name_class" id="<? php somefunction_which_echos_out_a_text ?>" value="<? php 

SAMEfunction_which_echos_out_a_text ?>" />

<input class = "select-change" type="button" id="<? php echo $recordx; ?>" value = "<? php echo $recordx; ?>" /><br>

<? PHP

}


function xyz(){    // I am calling it some where!!

connection...blah blah

echo "<select name = "dropdown1" id="dropdown1">";
echo "<option value="NULL">Select one</option>";

while($rec=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtxyz, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<option value='".$rec['con_code']."')>".$rec['con_name']."</option>";
}
</select>
}
?>
```

How can I map the textbox's text into the dropdown1 and select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with javascript function..not jquery..because of my ID problem for the textbox. Call the below function at onClick of the textbox and pass parameters.Thanks!

Here-

```
    function xyz(par){
    var dd1= document.getElementbyId('dropdown1');
    var opts = dd1.options.length;

    for (var i =0; i<opts; i++){

    if(document.getElementbyId('dropdown1').options[i].value == par){
        getElementbyId('dropdown1').selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may something like

```
  $(function() {
    $("#textboxID").on("change",function(){
         $("#selectBoxID").val($(this).val());
       //Set the option from dropdown list by textbox's value
    })
  });
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7sLzHYyDFHJZUWzCWJnj?p=preview)

Cheers!

Comment: My textbox ID is set by a php function, how do I deal with it?

Comment: Or else give me a way to set the textbox id for dynamically generated textboxes, I would then map it to the $("selectbox").val("HERE!")

Comment: Please don't forget I have dynamic textboxes

Comment: Since both ID and names are being set dynamically through php, you may select the textbox by its class name 
$(".con_name_class").on("change",function(){
});

Comment: How about $('.select-change').click(function(){

$('dropdown1').val($('.con_name_class').val());

}); Didn't help..shows blank on the dropdown1..after I click the button!

Answer (score 0):

I am modifyng NLN's code.You can give a specific part in name like "textbox_"

```
<input type="text" class="con_name_class" id="textbox_<? php somefunction_which_echos_out_a_text ?>" value="<? php SAMEfunction_which_echos_out_a_text ?>" />
```

Then use this script

```
 $(function() {
    $(input[id^="textbox_"]).on("change",function(){
         $("#selectBoxID").val($(this).val());
       //Set the option from dropdown list by textbox's value
    })
  });
```

Comment: I wrote it this way- 

$('.select-change').click(function(){

$('dropdown1').val($('input[id^="textbox_"').text());

});

And renamed the id of the textbox. On button click it blanked out the dropdown1

Comment: When I say alert($('input[id^="textbox_"').val());  IT PRINTS OUT THE VALUE!! However blanks out the dropdown1 when I wrote --      $('.select-change').click(function(){ $('dropdown1').val($('input[id^="textbox_"').val()); });

Comment: @Sunil..textbox_ is not the solution to differentiate the dynamic textboxes .. I checked it didn't work!! When I alert the $('input[id^="textbox_"').val()..from other buttons, they all print the same value(which is first textbox's ID) :(